# Calculate shipping for 1 product instead of whole cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have installed a plugin for calculating shipping costs in single product's page.
The plugin add the product in the cart calculate the shipping costs (whole cart + that product) and then removes it.

I want to calculate the shipping costs just for that product ( should be something like copy the currect cart, empty cart, add this product in cart calculate shipping , clean cart rollback the cart from the copy ?)
Anyone has a suggestion how to modify the code above in order to calculate for only the current product?

```
/* function for calculate shiiping */

    public function get_shipping_text($shipping_method, $country)
    {
        global $woocommerce, $post;
        $returnResponse = array();
        WC_Shortcode_Cart::calculate_shipping();


        if (isset($_POST["product_id"]) && $this->check_product_incart($_POST["product_id"]) === false) {
            $qty = (isset($_POST['current_qty']) && $_POST['current_qty'] > 0) ? $_POST['current_qty'] : 1;
            if (isset($_POST['variation_id']) && $_POST['variation_id'] != "" && $_POST['variation_id'] > 0) {
                $cart_item_key = WC()->cart->add_to_cart(sanitize_text_field($_POST["product_id"]), $qty, sanitize_text_field($_POST['variation_id']));
            } else {
                $cart_item_key = WC()->cart->add_to_cart(sanitize_text_field($_POST["product_id"]), $qty);
            }
            $packages = WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages();
            $packages = WC()->shipping->calculate_shipping($packages);
            $packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();
            WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($cart_item_key);
        } else {
            $packages = WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages();
            $packages = WC()->shipping->calculate_shipping($packages);
            $packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();
        }

        wc_clear_notices();

        if (isset($packages[0]["rates"][$shipping_method])) {
            $selectedShiiping = $packages[0]["rates"][$shipping_method];
            $returnResponse = array("label" => $selectedShiiping->label, "cost" => wc_price(($selectedShiiping->cost)*1.24));
        } else {
            $AllMethod = WC()->shipping->load_shipping_methods();
            $selectedMethod = $AllMethod[$shipping_method];
            $flag = 0;
            if ($selectedMethod->availability == "including"):
                foreach ($selectedMethod->countries as $methodcountry) {
                    if ($country == $methodcountry) {
                        $flag = 1;
                    }
                }
                if ($flag == 0):
                    $message = $selectedMethod->method_title . " is not available in selected country.";
                    $returnResponse = array("code" => "error", "message" => $message);
                endif;
            endif;
        }
        return $returnResponse;
    }
```

Comment: cleaning cart ...then rolling it back to calculate 1 product's shipping and then again removing that product ??? seems crazy idea to me....Should think something better ... like calculate shipping price for the product only.. without adding that to cart.

Comment: do you have any code to suggest ? :D

Comment: right now no... as i m not aware of which shipping method u r using.... bcoz all u need is to write is a function to calculate shipping for that method...but origin address and user address u will get easily

Comment: I need the modification for the current code in order to remove the cart's product from $packages and add only the current product. the function for calculating already exists.